# Java array assignment (multiple values)

Tags: java, variable-assignment

I have a Java array defined already e.g.

```
float[] values = new float[3];
```

I would like to do something like this further on in the code:

```
values = {0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f};
```

But that gives me a compile error. Is there a nicer way to define multiple values at once, rather than doing this?:

```
values[0] = 0.1f;
values[1] = 0.2f;
values[2] = 0.3f;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Yes:

```
float[] values = {0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f};
```

This syntax is *only* permissible in an initializer. You cannot use it in an assignment, where the following is the best you can do:

```
values = new float[3];
```

or

```
values = new float[] {0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f};
```

Trying to find a reference in the language spec for this, but it's as unreadable as ever. Anyone else find one?

Comment: I think this might be it, 10.6 Array Initializers, http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#11358

Comment: This seems to be the relevant part of the grammar: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#11358  - Personally, I've always found the java language spec to be very readable, compared with similar documents.

Comment: You may want to note that the bottom code creates a new array.

Comment: (If you want to find a really difficult spec, try the spec for Algol-68 ... with its 2 level grammar.  Search for "The Revised Algol-68 Report".)

Answer (score 9):

On declaration you can do the following.

```
float[] values = {0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f};
```

When the field is already defined, try this.

```
values = new float[] {0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f};
```

Be aware that also the second version creates a new array.
If `values` was the only reference to an already existing field, it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 4):

Java does not provide a construct that will *assign* of multiple values to an existing array's elements.  The initializer syntaxes can ONLY be used when creation a new array object.  This can be at the point of declaration, or later on.  But either way, the initializer is initializing a new array object, not updating an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

```
values = new float[] { 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the values at compile time you can do :

```
float[] values = {0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f};
```

There is no way to do that if values are variables in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but is slower and feels wrong: `System.arraycopy(new float[]{...}, 0, values, 0, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a local variable, like:

```
    float[] values = new float[3];
    float[] v = {0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f};
    float[] values = v;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class arrayFloats {
      public static void main (String [] args){
        float [] Values = new float[3];
        float Incre = 0.1f;
        int Count = 0;

        for (Count = 0;Count<3 ;Count++ ) {
          Values [Count] = Incre + 0.0f;
          Incre += 0.1f;
          System.out.println("Values [" + Count + "] : " + Values [Count]);
        }


      }
    }

//OUTPUT:
//Values [0] : 0.1
//Values [1] : 0.2
//Values [2] : 0.3
```

This isn't the all and be all of assigning values to a specific array. Since I've seen the sample was 0.1 - 0.3 you could do it this way. This method is very useful if you're designing charts and graphs. You can have the x-value incremented by 0.1 until nth time.

Or you want to design some grid of some sort.

Comment: adding a descriptive text may help others understand your answer

Answer (score 0):

for example i tried all above for characters it fails
but that worked for me >> reserved a pointer then assign values

```
char A[];
A = new char[]{'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'q', 'r'};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int a[] = { 2, 6, 8, 5, 4, 3 }; 
int b[] = { 2, 3, 4, 7 };
```

if you take float number then you take float and it's your choice

this is very good way to show array elements.