# How to define multiple variables in single statement

Tags: java, arrays

In Python, I can define two variables with an array in one line.

```
>>>[a,b] = [1,2]
>>>a
1
>>>b
2
```

How do I do the same thing in Java?

I have a couple of variables in class PCT which type is final. Is there a way to define them in one line in a Python like fashion? The following format clearly does not work in Java. I could define them separately, but it will call the parseFile method twice which I want to avoid.

```
public class PCT {
    final int start;
    final int stop;
    public PCT (File file) {
        //......
        //......
        // the following statement does not compile
        [start, stop] = parseFile(file);
    }
    public int[] parseFile(File f) {
        int[] aa = new int[2];
        // ....
        // ....
        return aa;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious as to why you would want this? For the sole purpose of reducing 2 lines to 1?

Comment: @noMAD: It is a quite convenient feature in the Python/Octave/Matlab/... world to pass/set multiple parameters in a single statement. Something the C/C++/Java family lacks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible, but you also don't need to call `parseFile` twice.

Write your code like this:

```
int [] temp = parseFile(file);
start = temp[0];
stop = temp[1];
```

Python (I believe) supports multiple return values. Java obeys C conventions, and so doesn't permit it. Since that isn't part of the language, the syntax for it isn't either, meaning slightly gross hacks like the `temp` array are needed if you're doing multiple returns.

Answer (score 18):

You can define multiple variables like this :

```
double a,b,c;
```

Each variable in one line can also be assigned to specific value too:

```
double a=3, b=5.2, c=3.5/3.5;
```

One more aspect is, while you are preparing common type variable in same line then from right assigned variables you can assign variable on left, for instance :

```
int a = 4, b = a+1, c=b*b;
```

Noticed, you can also practice arithmetic operations on variable by remaining in the same line.

Answer (score 3):

When declaring several variables of the same type, you can do the following:

```
int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3; //etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

If you literaly mean **line**; as long as you place a semicolon in between two statements, they are executed as if there is a new line in between so you can call:

```
a = 1; b = 2;
```

You can even compress an entire file into a oneliner, by removing comment (that scope to the end of the line). Spacing (space, tab, new line,...) is in general removed from the Java files (in memory) as first step in the Java compiler.

But you are probably more interested in a *singe statement*. Sytax like `[start, stop] = parseFile(file);` is not supported (at least not for now). You can make a onliner:

```
int[] data = parseFile(file); start = data[0]; stop = data[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
int array[] = {1,2};
```

[Java array assignment (multiple values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576038/java-array-assignment-multiple-values)

If you're looking to explicitly assign to each element, I don't think you can do that within one assignment, as a similar concept with the 2-d example below. Which seems like what you want as Jeremy's answers specifies.

[Explicitly assigning values to a 2D Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318113/explicitly-assigning-values-to-a-2d-array)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
public class PCT 
{
    final Point pos;  // two ints!

    public PCT (File file) 
    {
        pos = parseFile(file);
    }

    public int[] parseFile(File f) 
    {
        Point aa = new Point();
        // ....
        // ....
        return aa;
    }
}
```