# java variable assigned with multiple values

Tags: java

I have seen some question in Java ([question 15 here](https://www.ambitionbox.com/topics/java-programming/questions-and-answers/operators-and-assignments?page=2)), printing the value of `f` gives value as false

```
  boolean f = false,b;
  System.out.println(f); // prints false
```

But using two numeric values gives an error:
int x= 5,1;
System.out.println(x);

Reversing the assignment also gave me an error

```
boolean x = b,true;
```

> `A.java:7: error: <identifier> expected`

but `boolean x = true,b;` prints value of `x` is true!

Can some one explain how the code works?

Comment: "i have seen some question in java" can you link to that question?

Comment: https://www.ambitionbox.com/topics/java-programming/questions-and-answers/operators-and-assignments?page=2

Comment: see question 15

Comment: "explain how the code works" Where is the code that works? All examples here have some error or another

Comment: Joni just declare class name and main method and write two statements boolean f = false,b     and boolean x = b ,true   and print them

Comment: i will show  you the output picture

Comment: The line separators ; are not optional in Java, without them `boolean f = false, b System.out.println(f)` is a single statement and a syntax error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define multiple variables in single statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248287/how-to-define-multiple-variables-in-single-statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three part in variable declaration

1. Variable Type
2. Variable Name
3. Initial value

   [Primitive type]  [Primitive name] = [Initialization value]

**eg:**

```
 int totalQuantity = 100;
 int orderQuantity = 20;
```

where 3rd part is optional in general.

There is an another way to declare multiple properties in single statement separated by comma (,) while statement end with semi colon (;)

```
int totalQuantity =100, orderQuantity =20;
```

Now in your question

**case 1**

```
boolean f = false,b;
```

there are two variable declared with the name f and b of boolean type and f is initialized with false which is perfectly correct.

**case 2**

```
boolean x = b,true;
```

here two variables are x and true and x is initialized with b Here

- x is valid while variable name true is invalid name as per the rule
- in the initialization x = b, b is undefined. if you take first declaration of case 1 then x is initialized with b via its default value

Answer (score 3):

I think you might have mentally parsed the code wrongly.

`boolean f = false,b;` means:

> Declare a boolean variable `f`, initialise it with `false`, then declare another boolean variable `b`.

It doesn't mean:

> Declare a boolean variable `f`, initialise it with `false,b`

...whatever `false,b` means...

So `int x= 5,1;` doesn't work because `1` is not a valid variable name. The compiler thinks you are trying to declare another variable called `1`.

`boolean x = b,true;` doesn't work because `b`, which is supposed to be the initial value of `x`, is not defined.

I have added some spaces to help you parse this syntax:

```
boolean     f = false,      b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, as @Sweeper explained....
If you would have tried to print variable b too, from
`boolean f = false,b` , compiler would have warned you with reason

Comment: Not necessarily. The value of b is false because of default initialization.

Comment: True, if that's not in method level